# Force a result from "Indeterminate" for single impulse?

Tags: evaluation, warning-messages, trigonometry, boundary-condition-at-infinity

The formula for a single impulse of amplitude $1$ at $x=r$ is given by

$$\frac {\sin (\pi (x-r))}{\pi (x-r)}$$

(In MathJax because it's a math formula.)

Formally, at $x=r$, this function evaluates to $\frac {0}{0}$. As a result, understandably, Mathematica returns "Indeterminate". But analytically, the function *should* evaluate to $1$, as this is the limit of the function as $x$ approaches $r$ from either direction.

Is there a way to persuade Mathematica to evaluate the function to $1$ at this point?

(I'm only just learning Mathematica, so please be gentle!)

Comment: *"In MathJax because it's a math formula"*: please also provide Mathematica code, because this is a Mathematica forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Sinc[Pi(x-r)]`. `Sinc[z]` is defined as `Sin[z]/z` unless`z==0`, in which case it is `1`.

Answer (score 2):

By defining the following function:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sin[Pi (x - r)]/(Pi (x - r)), x != r}, {1, x == r}}]
```

the problem is solved, in fact `f[r] = 1`.